# Change individual cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

Need your advice:

1. I need to change view of all cells, when one exact cell is selected.
   Par example, I tap on the 5th cell and it changes the color of 4 previous cells
2. One of the cells can't be selected when the other ones are selected.
   Par example, the 5th cell can't be selected when one (or some) of the previous ones is selected.

Answer (score 0):

So add logic to your `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` delegate method that tells the table view to reload the affected cells. (You'll need to reload both the 4 previous cells and the 4 cells prior to the previously selected cell.)

Then update your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method to set the color of cells based on the currently selected cell.